# xmlhttp.responseText returns contents of the script tag

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
    <script>
function refresh_event(){//CALLED WHEN EVENT IS CHANGED
    document.getElementById("frm_event").submit();
}

function click1(i,stuid){//AJAX CODE
    var obj = document.getElementById("event");
    var eid = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var xmlhttp;

    var j=document.getElementById("link"+i).innerHTML;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            //alert("in");
            document.getElementById("link"+i).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        //  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    //alert("a"+j+"b");
    xmlhttp.open("GET","register.php?i="+j+"&sid="+stuid+"&eid="+eid+"&val=1&t="+Math.random(),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php 
if($val==0){//LANDING PAGE
?>
<?php
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "connection error";
    }
    $query="select name,eid from event_info";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<!-- CODE TO POPULATE EVENT LIST -->
<form id="frm_event" method="GET" action="register.php">
    Events:<select id="event" name="event" onchange="refresh_event()">
    <?php
        if($event==0){
    ?>
    <option value=0 selected> --select-- </option> <!-- IF NOTHING IS SELECTED -->
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <option value=0> --select-- </option>   <!-- IF EVENT IS SELECTED -->
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //FETCH EVENT FROM DATABASE
            if($event==$row['eid']){
    ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['eid'] ?> selected> <?=$row['name'] ?> </option>
    <?php
            }
            else{
    ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['eid'] ?>> <?=$row['name'] ?> </option>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
<?php
    $query="select stuid,name from stud_info";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $i=1;
?>
<br>
<table>
    <?php
        if($event==0){//IF EVENT IS NOT SET
    ?>
    <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <p><?=$row['name'] ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:click1(<?=$i ?>,<?=$row['stuid'] ?>);" name="link<?=$i ?>" id="link<?=$i ?>">Assign</a>
            <!--<a href="javascript:void(0);"  id="link<?=$i ?>" onclick="click()"> Assign 1</a>-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
                $i++;
            }
        }
        else{//IF EVENT IS SET
    ?>
    <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){//FETCH REGISTERED STUDENT FROM DATABASE
                $regid=0;
                $stuid=$row['stuid'];
                $query_event="select regid from event_register where stuid='$stuid' and eid='$event'";
                $result_event=mysqli_query($con,$query_event);
                $count1 = mysqli_num_rows($result_event);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <p><?=$row['name'] ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                if($count1>0){//IF STUDENT IS REGISTERED FOR THIS EVENT
            ?>
                <a href="javascript:click1(<?=$i ?>,<?=$row['stuid'] ?>);" name="link<?=$i ?>" id="link<?=$i ?> name=">Remove</a>
            <?php
                }
                else{
            ?>
                <a href="javascript:click1(<?=$i ?>,<?=$row['stuid'] ?>);" name="link<?=$i ?>" id="link<?=$i ?>">Assign</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
    //$_GET['change']="new";
    $val=0;//RESET THE VALUE
    $var =$_GET['i'];
    $sid = $_GET['sid'];
    $eid = $_GET['eid'];
    if($var=="Assign"){
    //INSERT QUERY
        $query="insert into event_register (stuid,eid) values ('$sid','$eid')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        echo "Remove";
    }
    else{
    //delete
        $query="delete from event_register where stuid='$sid' and eid='$eid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        //if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
            echo "Assign";
        //}
        /* else{
            echo "Assign";
        } */
    //return "return";
    }
}
?>
```

here is my code. using php and javacript. trying to fetch values from the databse using ajax. But the value returned by xmlhttp.responseText is giving problem.

above is the partial content of the script tag.
xmlhttp.responseText returns the entire contents of the script tag including the tag itself.

tried changing the getElementbyId to getElementsbyName still no luck.

the section of the code that executes on ajax call is at the end.

anyhelp is much appreciated.

Comment: It's getting the response that you're sending.

Comment: well it took my 20 mins to post this code since the original code that i was trying to post wasn't being accepted by stackoverflow. in the php all i am returning is 'echo "assign"'

Comment: added code for more clarity. the part that ajax calls is at the end part of the php code

Comment: Are you ajax-requesting the very same page on which the script is located? You shouldn't. Make an extra api that returns only the result table.

Comment: Yes my ajax is sending the request to the same page. My TL insists on including everything on the same page. He doesn't want additional pages/files created for small purposes. :|

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why it is happenning for you but it happened to me for the following reason: I had named my js and php file the same name, ex "script", and then in my js file, say "script.js", instead of setting handler url to script.php I set it to script.js, and so where as I might have had in my script.php, echo "resp on my php script", instead the whole text of my js file is read out.